# How to fetch multiple items from android sqlite database and store it in array?

Tags: android, sqlite

I m using static database to fetch data. I m fetching longitude and latitude of static location from database, storing it in string and using. What if i want to extract all longitude and latitude and store it in an array...i mean array of size [137][15] storing latitude and longitude in a single 2d array.....or 2 separate 1 d array. One for latitude ..another for latitude...

```
DataBaseHelper2 mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper2(this);
try {
    mDbHelper.createDataBase();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}      
try {
    mDbHelper.openDataBase();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}   
    Spinner s1=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    int index1=s1.getSelectedItemPosition();
    String Text1 = s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String Text3="";
    String Text4="";

    if(index1==0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Enter station", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
    Cursor c=mDbHelper.fetchQuery(Text1);

    int latitude =  c.getColumnIndex("lat");
    int longitude = c.getColumnIndex("lng");

    for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
        Text3=Text3 + c.getString(latitude)+"\n";
        Text4=Text4 + c.getString(longitude)+"\n";
    }

    Double p,p1;
    p=Double.valueOf(Text3).doubleValue();
    p1=Double.valueOf(Text4).doubleValue();
```

fetchquery is a method to extract longitude and latitude where name of station matches with text of spinner1.

Answer (score 0):

Use `List<BasicNameValuePair>` they will be stored in key-value manner. As you iterate store them add them in the list like:

```
List<BasicNameValuePair> latLongList = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
 for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
        latLongList.add(new BasicNameValuePair(c.getString(latitude), c.getString(longitude)));
    }
```

Then you can use it where ever you want. In thiscase latitude will be key and longitude will be value.

This is one way of doing this. Also instead `BasicNameValuePair` you can use `android.location.Location` and set in same manner.

Comment: Can we use BasicNameValuePair as arrays?

Comment: Its more convenient to use List, you dont care about indexes (unless needed) you just iterate over the list. And of course, you can use array of BasicNameValuePair. Like `BasicNameValuePair[]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll run into more trouble than it's worth using a 2 dimensional array for this. If you wanna persist 2 regular arrays, then perhaps you could check out the following code:

```
        if(index1==0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Enter station", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
        Cursor c=mDbHelper.fetchQuery(Text1);
        arrLatitude = new String [c.getCount()];
        arrLongitude = new String [c.getCount()];

        int latitude =  c.getColumnIndex("lat");
        int longitude = c.getColumnIndex("lng");

        i = 0;
        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
            Text3=Text3 + c.getString(latitude)+"\n";
            Text4=Text4 + c.getString(longitude)+"\n";
            arrLatitude[i] = Text3;
            arrLongitude[i] = Text4;
        i++;
        }
```

Personally, I'd rather do it with an object to hold both of these `Strings` together. That way you'd have peace of mind in case the indexes become mismatched for whatever reason.

Comment: Not working.....arrlatitude should store only 3rd latitude value...but its storing  latitude 1 to latitude 3.....

Comment: Sorry could you please elaborate or rephrase what the issue was?

Comment: I wanted to store the latitude and longitude colmuns as separate arrays...the solution u gave must have given latitude[3] as only 4th latitude but its storing values from 0th to 3rd....

Comment: I see, that has to do with how you wrote the `Text` strings. Remove the `Text3` and `Text4` to the right of the equal signs. These make it append the strings instead of replace them